# Project My screen in Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-640-xl, project-my-screen

After upgrading to Windows 10 Mobile, I cannot find one of my favourite Windows Phone feature: The [**Project My Screen**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10654/windows-phone-project-my-phone-screen-to-a-tv-or-pc) Functionality. I have tried searching through my settings, but I cannot seem to find the feature anywhere.

I have the [project my screen app](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42536) installed, and it functions well. I was using it with this very same phone when it was running Windows Phone 8.1 Update.

Is it still available in Windows 10 Mobile, or it was dumped. If it is there, please tell me how i can access it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still available in Windows 10 mobile. But you need to **connect your phone to a *USB 2.0* port on your computer** and don't use a USB 3.0 port.

For further reference see [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdsettings/project-my-screen-on-lumia-950-xl/4cfba826-2027-48f0-932e-7c6d59459c06?auth=1) from Microsoft community.

---

**In response to comments:** Now a days, most of the computers and have laptops have USB 3.0 ports as well as USB 2.0 ports. Your phone screen will not project if you are connecting your phone on a USB 3.0 port. Normally in Laptops you will have USB 2.0 ports on one side and 3.0 on the other. If you are unsure which is the USB 2.0 port try all the USB pors. If your computer has only 3.0 ports then currently you cannot use this app.

You can also find the USB ports in the device manager. Particulary a USB 3.0 port will have its version mentioned. See the screenshot below out of all my USB ports the only one USB 3.0 port has it's has it's version number mentioned on the device manager.

[image]

Comment: Okay. But I cannot find the option under settings...!!

Comment: @Kelvinelove Under Settings!!! I never told to look in settings. Connect your phone to a USB 2.0 port that your computer has. That's all. I will update my answer to add more clarification.

Comment: @Kelvinelove Updated my answer. Hope you get the idea now. If my answer is not clear enough for you feel free to ask.

Comment: "you need to connect your phone to a USB 2.0 port" - "Your phone screen will not project if you are connecting your phone on a USB 2.0 port". Wait, so which is it? And why will projecting the screen only work on one type of USB port and not the other?

Comment: @Indrek I don't the reason for it. I faced the same problem. My lap has a USB 3.0 and 2*USB2.0 ports. It was in the technical description of my Laptop model on Flipkart, Amazon,etc... I found the USB ports by the no of ports. You can also use the Device Manager if you want. It was previously(in WP8.1) working with my USB 3.0 port, but after the upgrade it stopped working. I searched for a solution and found this thread. I tried connecting the device via a USB 2.0. To my surprise it worked. I saw this question here and posted that as an answer. I don't how but it works, worked  for me.

Comment: I mean, which type of USB port are you supposed to connect to - 2.0 or 3.0? You have two conflicting statements in your post (the ones I quoted).

Comment: Oh. It's 2.0 you have to connect to. I'll correct the post. thanks for noting me.